# Maven: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, maven

I have the following configuration for my maven build and I have double checked the class name as well as package name multiple times to ensure it's accuracy. But everytime I run:
`java -jar <snapshot-with-dependencies>.jar` I get `Error: Could not find or load main class com.atlassian.JiraRestCaller`.
The excerpt from my pom file is as below

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.atlassian.JiraRestCaller</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I also tried adding `<sourceDirectory>src/main/java/com/atlassian/</sourceDirectory>` but still get the same error

Comment: Show output from `jar tvf your.jar`

Comment: Hi @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen i figured out the issue - which seems odd to me but might make sense to you - the code was written using Java1.8 -- the system maven was running on was 1.7. As soon as I upgraded maven to use 1.8 everything is working fine.

Comment: That error message does not indicate that to be the problem.  Then you missed something else earlier or did something you didn't mention.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution1:**

I spent a decent amount of time trying to solve this problem. I thought that I was somehow setting my classpath incorrectly but the problem was that I typed:

```
java -cp C:/java/MyClasses C:/java/MyClasses/utilities/myapp/Cool
```

instead of:

```
java -cp C:/java/MyClasses utilities/myapp/Cool
```

I thought the meaning of fully qualified meant to include the full path name instead of the full package name.

**Solution2:**

If you use Maven to build the JAR file, please make sure to specify the main class in the pom.xml file:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>class name us.com.test.abc.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: thank you for your tips. I did infact provide the name of of my main class. It is in the pom file (as part of my question). I am using maven to compile the executable jar

Answer (score 0):

This might help you if your case is specifically like mine: as a beginner I also ran into this problem when I tried to run a Java program.

I compiled it like this:

```
javac HelloWorld.java
```

And I tried to run also with the same extension:

```
java Helloworld.java
```

When I removed the .java and rewrote the command like java HelloWorld, the program ran perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

So we had this today

[myproject]-[master] $ mvn
[MVNVM] Using maven: 3.5.2
Error: Could not find or load main class html

and we had an issue with Proxies.

Check your MAVEN_OPTS and make sure that if you are sending in a proxy to maven, that it exists and you can use it.

MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=www-proxy.myproxyprovider.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.proxyHost=www-proxy.myproxyprovider.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=80

or if it is set and you shouldnt have one, then get rid of it.

[myproject]-[master] $ mvn -version
[MVNVM] Using maven: 3.5.2
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T08:58:13+01:00)
Maven home: /Users/bamcgill/.mvnvm/apache-maven-3.5.2

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same error. I fixed it by upgrading from Maven 3.3.3 to Maven 3.6.3. I am not sure whether that fix is related to this question, because I did not debug my issue.